# Why this before_action is not working? Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to apply DRY in my code but is not working. On the methods show, edit, update and delete I have to implement a find by id. I created a private method called "set_book" and implement "before_action". It seems right but the views are not working. On show, for example, seems that 'find by id' is not there.

**NoMethodError in Books#show
Showing /home/morganaborges/code/MorganaTBorges/bamboleio_project/app/views/books/show.html.erb where line #2 raised:
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass**

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_book, only: %i[show, edit, update, delete]

  def index
    @books = Book.paginate(:page => params[:page], per_page: 10)
    @active_books = @books.select { |book| book.deleted === nil }
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @book = Book.new
  end

  def create
    @book = Book.new(book_params)
    @book.created_by = current_user.id
    if @book.save
      redirect_to book_path(@book), notice: 'O livro foi criado com sucesso.'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    @book.updated_by = current_user.id
    if @book.update(book_params)
      redirect_to @book, notice: 'O livro foi editado com sucesso.'
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def delete
    @book.deleted = 1
    @book.save
    redirect_to books_url, notice: 'O livro foi removido com sucesso.'
  end

  def deleted
    @books = Book.paginate(:page => params[:page], per_page: 10)
    @deleted_books = @books.select { |book| book.deleted === 1 }
  end


  private

  def book_params
    params.require(:book).permit(:name, :title, :featured, :minimum_age, :maximum_age, :key_words, 
                                :link, :summary, :format, :cover, :tips, :audio, :subtitle, :video,
                                :status, :start_online, :end_online, :deleted)
  end

  def set_book
    @book = Book.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

Comment: Paste your code for the show.html.erb

Comment: Looks like you've typed in a url for a book that doesn't exist.  Create a book,  get its id, and type that id into the URL. It should now work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change

```
before_action :set_book, only: %i[show, edit, update, delete]
```

to

```
before_action :set_book, only: %i[show edit update delete]
```

Explanation

```
2.6.5 :001 > %i[show, edit, update, delete]
 => [:"show,", :"edit,", :"update,", :delete]
2.6.5 :002 > %i[show edit update delete]
 => [:show, :edit, :update, :delete]
```

So, in your case `set_book` method is not calling for the `show` method but for `show,` & hence it might not working for you.

Note:- You should use `@book.name` in your show.html.erb